# Overriding bootstrap 4 $primary variable not applied globally when using in custom _variables.scss

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I am making one HTML theme using BootStrap 4.3.1. My goal is to override $primary color variable in my theme `_variables.scss` that I think, It should change all colors globally according to BootStrap's `_variables.scss` in my theme. I am new to BootStrap 4 so please could you be kind enough to help me instead of marking my question flagged/duplicated?

I will give one example here that what I want to achieve:

I think that according to my knowledge, by overriding just `$primary` color variable in my custom `_variables.scss` should also change the color of `$dropdown-link-active-bg` without overriding `$dropdown-link-active-bg` because `$dropdown-link-active-bg` color is set to directly `$primary` color. Is this correct or I am doing anything wrong here?

I have put this much in my custom _variables.scss code:

```
$primary: #f00;
```

Here is my theme.scss file:

```css
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/scss/variables";


// User Variables
@import "user-variables";

// Theme variables and mixins 
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";


//Bootstrap core
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Extended Bootstrap components
@import "custom/dropdowns.scss";

// Core CSS
@import "core/general.scss";
@import "core/typography.scss";

// Shortcodes
@import "components.scss";

//In This scss you can write your scss
@import "user";
```

Please help me with this. I would greatly appreciate that. At the end I just want to know that Would I need to override `$dropdown-link-active-bg` variable or not to change its color? If not, What I am doing wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: Try importing your own variables before Bootstrap's

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I wanted to give this a try before but I thought it could be wrong approach to import bootstrap variables after my custom one. Thanks for taking time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your _variables.scss file before any bootstrap files.